# Sorting columns of a csv file using pyspark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

For my homework I must sort a csv file of two columns in order to make a bar diagram. This is the content of the csv file:

[image]

How can I sort by year, because my bar diagram gets messy?

Comment: do you want to do it using spark? or any method will do? using spark is an overkill for this simple task.

Comment: I am supposed not to touch the file by good old fashioned editing :-)

Comment: no, i mean, python will do the job perfectly, no need for spark

Comment: Unfortunately I must use pyspark :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spark.read.csv('input.csv', header=True).coalesce(1).orderBy('year').write.csv('output',header=True)
```

Or if you want a named csv file instead of a part-xxx.csv file inside a named folder,

```
spark.read.csv('input.csv', header=True).coalesce(1).orderBy('year').toPandas().to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thx ! Is it too much to ask you if I can rename column "count" before saving ?

Comment: @GiannisStas you can, just add `.withColumn('count', 'new_name')` before `.coalesce(1)`